# XML Serializer fails processing large XML data

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, xml-serialization

I know this must be straight forward but somehow I am not able to get my head around it.

-- Scenario --

We are using a system which has a WPF front end, then a DB first entity framework and then a SQL 2008R2 database.

most of the entities that we have are parent child relations. A parent cannot exist without children and hence the stored procedures that we have take

Parent Data and list of child data, here list of child data is passed as XML after serializing the entire list using XML Serializer.

All this was working fine until we have to save 500,000 child records.
when we try to do this XML Serializer fails complaining about out of memory.
Then I tried to send child records in batches of 10,000 which executes the query and saves the data but atomicity is then lost coz its just a for loop like this..

```
 For Each batchList In groups.Split(10000)
     Dim serializer As New XmlListSerializer(Of someObject)(batchList.ToList(), "Data")
     Dim xml = serializer.ToXmlString
     efContext.AddData(CType(addedParentId.Value, Short?), xml, "/Data/someObject")
 Next
```

Where add data is function import mapped to stored procedure.

-- Question --

Now my question here is, what is the right way to add multiple child records into database while keeping the atomicity of the operation active.

Also, the above mentioned way is dead slow, for hald million recortds it takes 5 minutes which is not acceptable anyway.

Comment: Your problem seems more related to xml serialization than to batching data to ddbb.. In fact you don't hit ddbb till you don't call context.save, which is not part of your code

Comment: yes, I agree to that, xmlserializer has issued with dynamic assembly loading that causes problems, I am wondering what other people do in such scenarios or is xml serialization is the finest way to handle such cases ?

Comment: I think casting batchList to an Enumerable type (AsEnumerable()) might help. Also most of the time I use Json object rather than XML since its lighter

Comment: batch list is IEnumerable, and I haven't tried json deserialzation.. will try that next.. do you have any experience working with it with a huge collection ?

Comment: Why not store data as regular data instead of xml? It's a bussines requirement?

Comment: whats regular data Oscar ? sorry didn't catch that quite well ? I just need to send a collection to db any which way

Comment: @Muds I mean storing data in rows and columns, instead of xml

Comment: data is stored in rows and column, we translate all the data to xml so that we can transfer all the rows in one go, then db handles the xml and extracts data from it to insert into rows and columns

Answer (score 1):

> what is the right way to add multiple child records into database
>   while keeping the atomicity of the operation active.

The way you do this is by [making a Transaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx) you start before you your multiple steps then commit or rollback at the end. In-fact Entity Framework is already doing this when it does multiple inserts in one `SaveChanges()` call. Which brings us to:

> Also, the above mentioned way is dead slow, for half million records
>   it takes 5 minutes which is not acceptable anyway.

Entity framework is NOT designed for bulk operations, each one of those 500,000 records will generate a separate `INSERT INTO` statement. Either use a [extension for EF](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/) that provides bulk insert abilities or use old fashioned ADO.NET with [`SqlBulkCopy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) to load the data.

---

As for the XML issue, if your children list are that big the "correct" thing to do is don't use XML. Parent and child should be separate tables in the database, you would then have a 3rd "linking table" which would be

```
create table Parent_Child_Links
{
    ParentId int,
    ChildId int
}
```

When you have a Many to Many table relationship and you let Entity Framework make your tables for you it would have made that 3rd linking table with foreign keys pointing at the two tables.

Comment: transactions I believe come into action when I command EF to do multiple things, but when I am calling ef.AddSomething multiple times, how should I keep them in a transaction ?

Comment: `AddSomthing` (and `AddData` you used in your question) is not a method of [`DbContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx) so I could not tell you, what you do need to do is open a transaction before the first call to [`SaveChanges()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges(v=vs.113).aspx) then commit the transaction after you have called the last call to `SaveChanges()`. If `ef.AddSomthing` calls `SaveChanges()` interally, then yes you do need to start a transaction before you call it.

Comment: If `AddData` does call `SaveChanges` then you would do `Using transaction as DbContextTransaction efContext.Database.BeginTransaction()` before your `For Each` then after the line after the `Next` you do `transaction.Commit()` then the next line `End Using` (I am a C# guy so that VB.NET may have a syntax error or two)

Comment: Thanks Scott, I am quite new with ef, I cant see any .Database in efcontext.... is that version dependent ?

Comment: No, I assumed `efcontext` was a class derived from `DbContext`, what is `efcontext`?

Comment: your statement holds true but only after ef v4.1

Comment: Muds is correct, I did not even think about it because 4.0 and 3.5 (there is no versions older, the version number was numbered to match the .NET framework it shipped with) is such a old version I would not think new development would be done with it.

Comment: upgrading now Scott ! thanks for the much needed kick !